# Is there a web app allow me to search through large repositories of code?

Tags: webapp-rec

If I am looking for a particular C# language construct or how to use a keyword in JavaScript, I would like to search only in code, not in blog paragraphs *about* code.

I thought I could do this at code.google.com but there if I type in e.g.

> "protected internal"

I get *discussions* about that keyword and have to look through the results to find actual code.

**What are some web app search machines which allow me to search through large repositories of code only?**

Comment: You could try a google search query instead `protected internal inurl:browse site:code.google.com`

Answer (score 4):

[Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch).

Try this: "[protect internal](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=%22protected+internal%22&hl=en&btnG=Search+Code)"

Answer (score 1):

[GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) lets you [search](http://github.com/search) through code.

[image]
<sub>(source: [skitch.com](http://img.skitch.com/20081103-djha3wqay51m5fymfddsh57ed2.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

## Krugle

You can also search that in [Krugle](http://www.krugle.org/kse/entfiles?query=%22protected%20internal%22&lang=c%23).

Answer (score 0):

Just remembered another one: [Koders.com](http://www.koders.com/)